# How do I move to a UNC location and enter its password via a script?

Tags: scripting, batch-file, dos

I want to move my current path to some network UNC password protected path.
I need to do it via batch script.
How do I move to that UNC location and enter its password via a script?
I thought doing it like `pushd \\my\path` but how do I enter the username and password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cmdkey`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754243(WS.10).aspx) or [`net use`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_use)